# Some intents not displayed in preview portal https://preview.eu.luis.ai/

Tags: preview, azure-language-understanding, portal

When accessing a model via the preview portal I can see only a subset of the intents compared to the production portal. I can see the missing intents in the old portal, or if I use the search function in the new portal. There is a bug in the display of the intent list.

Comment: Feel free to use the smile icon in the portal to submit the feedback to product team.

Comment: I've been advised before to post issues on UserVoice (even though it asks more for suggestions). You may give that a try. https://cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/551524-language-understanding-luis You can also find the github site and raise an issue there. SO isn't the right place to post bug reports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please feel free to use the smile icon in the portal to submit the feedback to product team.

[image]